# Laravel Display table product if not exist on quantity table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

In PHP-MySQL I can create this query...

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM product"; 
$result = $conn->query($,con, $sql);
while($row =mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $sqlquantity = "SELECT * FROM quantity where branchid='4' and productid='$row['productid']'"; 
    $resultquantity = $conn->query($,con, $sqlquantity);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($resultquantity) == 0) {
        echo $row['productname']. "not available in branch"
    }
    else {
         echo $row['productname']. "available in branch"
    }
}
```

But how can I do this using Laravel?

I have 3 tables

```
  +-----------------+   +-----------------+    +----------------+ 
  |  product table  |   | quantity table  |    |  branch table  |
  +-----------------+   +-----------------+    +----------------+
  |   id            |   |  productid      |    |   id           |
  |   productname   |   |  branchid       |    |   branchname   |
  +-----------------+   |  quantity       |    +----------------+
                        +-----------------+
```

My problem is that I am trying to create a `model`, `view` and `controller` where I can display all the `products` that is not available yet on each `branch` base on the `quantity` table. Can anyone help?

Product model

```
public function quantity()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Quantity', 'productid', 'id');
}
```

Quantity model

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'productid', 'id');
}
```

Branch Model

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Quantity', 'branchid', 'id');
}
```

What I am trying to create is that if I view the `branch` I can add those `product` `quantity` table if the `product` does not exist.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki this is not working as branchid is on Quantity table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try this one...

Please check **many-to-many** relationship at the [Official Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) for better explanation. .

You don't need to create a `Quantity` model because it serves as a `pivot` or joining table (not an entity) between `Product` and `Branch` model. Since you have custom pivot table name, which is `quantity` you need to pass it to the 2nd argument or else Eloquent will automatically create a table name for you which is `branch_product` (alphabetical). 3rd and 4th arguments are foreign keys of current model and the joining model respectively.

**Product model**

```
public function branches()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Branch', 'quantity', 'productid', 'branchid')
                ->withPivot('quantity');  //additional pivot column 
}
```

**Branch model**

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'quantity', 'branchid', 'productid')
                ->withPivot('quantity');
}
```

**Product Controller**

```
 $products = Product::all();

 if($products){
    $x = 0;

    foreach ($products as $prod) {

         $products[$x] = $prod->branches()
         //  ->wherePivot('productid', '=', $prod->id)
             ->wherePivot('branchid', '=', 4)
             ->wherePivot('quantity', '=', 0)
             ->get();
         $x++;
    }
  }

  return response(['products' => $products],200); 
        //get all the products in branch 4 with quantity = 0
```

Then you could do the conditional `if` to determine if it is available or not.

Comment: Glad it helps. Does it answers your problem?

Comment: yes.. I got it but I have another problem arise.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `whereHas()` method like :

```
Product::whereHas( 'Quantity', function($sQuery){
    $sQuery->where('branchid', 4);
})->get();
```